# Mediaplayer does not start again and plays on background

Tags: media-player

i´m a very beginner on android/java, i created a code when user press the button, it starts a song, everything its fine but i´m having 2 issues:

1- When the song ends, it does not play again when i hit the button once more, i need to kill app.

2- When the song is playing and i press home/back, the song still playing on background.

HERE iS THE CODE----

```
Button play;
MediaPlayer musica;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_play);
    final MediaPlayer musica = new MediaPlayer();

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (musica.isPlaying()) {
                musica.stop();
                musica.reset();
            }
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                afd = getAssets().openFd("cdztriste.mp3");
                musica.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                        afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                musica.prepare();
                musica.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onBackPressed function, type

```
this.finish();
```

it should work.
Do you have two buttons? one for reset and one for play?